# Can I show more context in a Github diff?

Tags: git, github

In both the Github client for Mac OS X and Github on the web, a diff only shows 3 lines of context (lines above and below the change).

Is there any way to show more lines of context in Github?

Comment: This is not the github helpdesk

Comment: @TimCastelijns i understand that, but i believe this is a question some of developers at Stackoverflow must have faced too and can give their 2 cents for the same

Comment: The way you phrased it makes it sound like a feature request for the github team

Comment: My bad :) Not the best man to juggle with words. Is it not possible then ? I thought it was some setting in maybe some .git* file

Comment: Edited to make it sound less helpdesk-y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `git diff` on the command line, the `-U` option set the amount of contest to use.  So for example `git diff -U10 file` will show the differences between your working version of `file` and the index version, with 10 lines of context.

If you're using a GUI client it may have a config param buried somewhere in a preferences menu.  Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a gitconfig variable to set this.