# Git diff only show context above diff (like grep -A0 -B5)

Tags: git, git-diff

[`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) has the `-U` / `--unified` option that

> Generate diffs with <n> lines of context instead of the usual three

Questions regarding this option have been asked multiple times:

- [Git: show more context when using git add -i or git add -e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711670/git-show-more-context-when-using-git-add-i-or-git-add-e)
- [change no of lines after and before in git diff output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638261/change-no-of-lines-after-and-before-in-git-diff-output)
- [Can I show more context in a Github diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990378/can-i-show-more-context-in-a-github-diff)
- [How can I get "git show" to show diffs with full context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857967/how-can-i-get-git-show-to-show-diffs-with-full-context)

---

However, none of those questions, nor the man page, mention any way of **changing the context depending on the direction**.

For example, [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) has the following 'context control options':

```
After:   -A NUM  --after-context=NUM
Before:  -B NUM  --before-context=NUM
Around:  -C NUM  --context=NUM
```

So I can use `seq 1 10 | grep 5 -A0 -B10` to only get the context **above** the matching line, in this example it will output row `1 - 5`

---

##### **Question**:

How can I extend my `git diff` command to **only** show the <n> lines **above the diff**?

Comment: You might be able to do something with [`git difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool). Unfortunately, GNU diff doesn't have Before and After context options only, so `git difftool -y -x 'diff -A0 -B10'` won't work.